# Use iptables nat to redirect gateway for LAN PCs

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I have a Linux server which functions as the gateway for my home network. It has two ethernet devices:

- `p3p1`: WAN, public IP address `a.b.c.d`
- `p2p1`: LAN, private IP address `10.0.3.1/24`

It also connects via a *point-to-point* OpenVPN tunnel to a remote Linux server (which I also administrate). This adds the device

- `tun2`: VPN, private IP address `10.2.0.2/32`

The question is: **how do I make all traffic from clients on the LAN redirect through the OpenVPN tunnel?**

I can redirect *all* traffic (including that originating from the gateway server) using the VPN client configuration option `redirect-gateway def1`. But that isn't what I want.

Would there be a way to do this using IPTables NAT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this using policy based IP routing, as A. Fendt mentioned in a comment:

1. Insert a new IP routing table:

`$ echo "200 vpndef1" | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

2. Add routes for the VPN redirect:

`$ sudo ip route add 10.0.3.0/24 via 10.0.3.1 dev p2p1 table vpndef1
$ sudo ip route add default via 10.2.0.1 dev tun2 table vpndef1`

3. Insert a new rule to direct LAN traffic to the new routing table:

`$ sudo ip rule add from 10.0.3.0/24 lookup vpndef1`

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Steps you should do:

1. In the first step your local DHCP Server has to configure the Client default gateway to your Server Address `10.0.3.1`
2. Then use the [routing policy database](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html) to route your local network traffic to the VPN Default Gateway behind `p2p1` and route your servers traffic to the default gateway behind `p3p1`
3. After that you have to `MASQUERADE` your traffic which comes from your local network and goes into the VPN:

> ```
> # enable ip forwarding
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
>
> # configure iptables
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 -d 10.2.0.2/32 -j MASQUERADE
> iptables -P FORWARD DROP
> iptables -A FORWARD -i p2p1 -o tun2 -j ACCEPT
> iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> ```

Comment: The default gateway is already set to the server. I don't want to redirect all traffic, only traffic originating from the LAN (i.e. I don't want to redirect traffic from the server itself over the VPN).

Comment: In this case remove the `redirect-gateway def1` directive and create some policy based routing entries: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html As you said: every traffic from the local network goes to the VPN Default Gateway and the traffic of the server goes to the Default Gateway behind p3p1.